# How to search for files in directory and subdirectories using a single path

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio

I am trying to search for files with extensions "*.xml" & "*.pdf" in multiple directories under a single path.

But here the problem is that the directories consist of many sub directories and i have to read the sub directory which consist of "*.xml" & "*.pdf" files under a single path And if any one of the files are missing in sub directory the code should be able to get that particular main directory name.

Please anyone help me out with this,

Any help will be really appreciated

Comment: All CAPS is not welcome.

Answer (score 4):

Since the availability of Stacks in VB, I've used them over recursion because of it's simplicity to debug and less chance of a recursive routine getting out of hand.

```
    Function SearchForFiles(ByVal RootFolder As String, ByVal FileFilter() As String) As List(Of String)
    Dim ReturnedData As New List(Of String)                             'List to hold the search results
    Dim FolderStack As New Stack(Of String)                             'Stack for searching the folders
    FolderStack.Push(RootFolder)                                        'Start at the specified root folder
    Do While FolderStack.Count > 0                                      'While there are things in the stack
        Dim ThisFolder As String = FolderStack.Pop                      'Grab the next folder to process
        Try                                                             'Use a try to catch any errors
            For Each SubFolder In GetDirectories(ThisFolder)            'Loop through each sub folder in this folder
                FolderStack.Push(SubFolder)                             'Add to the stack for further processing
            Next                                                        'Process next sub folder
            For Each FileExt In FileFilter                              'For each File filter specified
                ReturnedData.AddRange(GetFiles(ThisFolder, FileExt))    'Search for and return the matched file names
            Next                                                        'Process next FileFilter
        Catch ex As Exception                                           'For simplicity sake
        End Try                                                         'We'll ignore the errors
    Loop                                                                'Process next folder in the stack
    Return ReturnedData                                                 'Return the list of files that match
End Function
```

Make sure you include `Imports System.Io.Directory` at the top of your source file.  Calling is simple:

```
Dim Files = SearchForFiles("D:\Programming_VS\", {"*.xml", "*.pdf"})
```

Which returns a list of strings containing the searched for files.

Answer (score 1):

This should at least get you started. It uses recursion to search through files in folders and subfolders.

```
Public Sub rec(ByVal SourcePath As String)
    Dim SourceDir As DirectoryInfo = New DirectoryInfo(SourcePath)
    Dim pathIndex As Integer
    pathIndex = SourcePath.LastIndexOf("\")
    ' the source directory must exist, otherwise throw an exception

    If SourceDir.Exists Then
        Dim SubDir As DirectoryInfo
        For Each SubDir In SourceDir.GetDirectories()
            Console.WriteLine(SubDir.Name)
            rec(SubDir.FullName)
        Next


        For Each childFile As FileInfo In SourceDir.GetFiles("*", SearchOption.AllDirectories).Where(Function(file) file.Extension.ToLower = ".pdf" Or file.Extension.ToLower = ".docx")
            Console.WriteLine(childFile.Name)
        Next
    Else
        Throw New DirectoryNotFoundException("Source directory does not exist: " + SourceDir.FullName)
    End If

End Sub
```

Sample Usage

```
rec("C:\MyFiles")
```

Comment: is there any way to find two files with different extensions together in a subdirectory..

Comment: yes, use `childFile.extension` to get the extension of the file you want to find, and then get the logic by setting conditions (if - else statements, select case, etc.)

Comment: see i have done like this `childFile As FileInfo In SourceDir.GetFiles("*.xml",searchoption.searchalldirectories)` in this i am able to find xml files and unable to insert another files extension...so is there any way to do both together..

Comment: ok now i have to check whether both the files are available in subdirectory of all directories in a single path if anyone of file is missing then it should display the directory name in vch the files are missing..sry to bother u bt m new at this

Answer (score 0):

You can traverse all the files and Sub folders in the Folder.

```
Const startDir = "c:\"
Set oFSO   = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject") 
Set oFolder = oFSO.GetFolder(startDir)
Traverse(oFolder)

Sub Traverse(oFldr)
    For Each oSubFolder In oFldr.SubFolders
         TraverseoSubFolder
    Next 

    For Each oFile In oFldr.Files
        //search for the files with extension you required
    Next 
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Returns the file path for a file by searching all folders and sub folders in a 
 location that is passed as a parameter to the below function

```
        Dim filepath As String = ""
        Dim SourceDir As DirectoryInfo = New DirectoryInfo(AppSettings.Get("mapped_location") + "\AA7BB3B5\TIFF\")
        For Each childFile As FileInfo In SourceDir.GetFiles("*", SearchOption.AllDirectories).Where(Function(file) file.Extension.ToLower = ".tif")
            If childFile.FullName.ToString.Contains(sSelectedfile) Then
                filepath = childFile.FullName
            End If
        Next
        Return filepath
    End Function
```